# How much time should I account for security in Brussels airport?

Tags: airport-security, bru

I flew from Brussels aiport, a couple of months ago, after the explosions. Back then security had more layers and part of it was setup outside.
I went 3 hours in advance (relating to flight time) to be sure I would get the airplane. Everything was relatively fluid, but with huge queues and different routing schemes for passengers things take more time.

How is it currently? Do I still need to account for the same amount of time?
Are there better/worse periods along the day?

Comment: what passport are you on?

Comment: I am an EU citizen inside Schengen space

Comment: i went there 2 years ago before the explosions and security was  a ~20min walk with some queques, i guess if everything is back to normal, that's the average you'll find.

Comment: @mts Average waiting time for the regular safety check is not really the main concern, the question is additional checks at the entrance of the airport or before reaching the terminal building.

Comment: @CptEric Definitely not back to normal, for example the Kiss&Ride area is still closed and there are additional pre-screening checkpoints. I went through the airport by train a couple of weeks ago and apparently you can't leave the station without a plane ticket or something…

Comment: There is a page [suggesting the additional security measures have been scaled down but remain partially in place](http://www.brusselsairport.be/en/passngr/tempdeppax/secmeasures/). I have no idea how things actually are on the ground.

Comment: @mts I believe that is the standard FAQ, not reflecting the current status or the addtitional checks.

Answer (score 6):

There are newspaper articles stating that the security measures have again relaxed, e.g. [this one](http://www.flanderstoday.eu/current-affairs/brussels-airport-revises-check-times-security-measures-are-relaxed). Therefore, the queues should not be that big as they used to be. Actually, according to [their own FAQ](http://www.brusselsairport.be/en/contact/faq_all/faq007/), the waiting time should never be more than 10 minutes. However, this sounds a little bit optimistic.

The best thing however is to get the real data. The [Brussel Airport app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.brusselsairport.appyflight&hl=en) provides security waiting times in real time. You could check these waiting times periodically the days before your flight to get a feeling.

Comment: Is the app for all security queues? I can imagine they wouldn't change it for a temporary situation?

Answer (score 5):

I went very recently through Brussels Airport. It was a Saturday afternoon and therefore I am not sure how that influences the experience since there might be less people flying.

There is a new security check before entering the airport. It was quite easy and there was no queue at all.

Inside the airport the process is similar to what it was. At least from a user perspective. The queue was minimal and the staff helpful trying to make the process smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I flew recently from Brussels airport and security is regularized with no significant delays.